# Identify Facebook users who have hidden their info from apps

Tags: facebook, api, privacy

Facebook gives users control over the info they share with apps and also "How people bring your info to apps they use" (https://skitch.com/nicksoman/emqhx/privacy-settings).

The Facebook API returns a blank for any info that's not available, whether that's because 1) the user hasn't listed it or 2) the user has blocked app access to it.

Is it possible to differentiate between those two sets? In other words, when we try to pull something like location and it returns a blank, is it possible for us to tell the difference between someone who has their location set to blank and someone who's just not sharing it with apps?

Would love any advice on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not possible to differentiate between the two cases, but note that the 'How people bring your info to apps they use' setting only refers to your app user's friends, not users who are actually using your app

Comment: Thanks Igy. But doesn't the same problem exist for users of the app? I believe the same settings will hide my info from apps I sign into. So if I uncheck location and sign into an app that requests it, the app will get the rest of my info but not get that. Do you have a different understanding?

Comment: No, If a user authorises your app, all their data (subject to you having the correct [Permissions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/), of course) is available - there's no privacy settings that control this other than their granting/not granting of the pieces of data you've requested

Comment: Igy, thanks again for the help. Just to confirm, I think you're saying this: If the API returns a blank for location for an app users' friend, there's no way to tell based on what is returned whether that friend has no location set or just isn't sharing that info with apps, AND no way to check the friends' privacy settings to see whether they're sharing location with apps. Is that correct?

Comment: Correct, there's no API which returns those settings. For your app's user a call to `/me/permissions` will show you the current user's granted permissions, but you can't see what their friends' settings are

Answer (score 0):

I think you could also use the permissions endpoint https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me%2Fpermissions to see what permissions a user has granted your application. You can then see if they have granted your app the appropriate permission for what you want and if so you can tell if it's just blank

Comment: Thanks Tommy. This works for users, but can you use a similar endpoint to see the "How people bring your info to apps they use" settings for users' friends?